# Android O - implement ResourcesCompat.getFont

Tags: android, typeface

I'm trying to implement new Android O font resource functionality with AppCompat 26. It works fine on a device with SDK 26.

I get an error with command:

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.barcode);
```

> Function returns error:  *Invalid int: "res/font/barcode_font.ttf"

What does it mean? Looks like app compact is not loaded correctly. Am I right?
Is it possible that app compact 26 new font functionality is overridden with another dependency?

I will not post my app code here because I've made this app since 2013 and it has a lot of old stuff in it.

My simple test app works fine, so I know how to use Google development/Internet examples.

***I just need to understand what does this error mean.***

Some code just to check the basics.

My barcode.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/barcode_font"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/barcode_font"/>
</font-family>
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    compileOptions.encoding = "UTF-8"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pl.acme_gliwice.smieciarka"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 350
        versionName "2.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),             'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'mediarouter-v7'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
    implementation('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    compile files('libs/bluetoothservices.jar'){}
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/javaproj-1.0.6-noawt.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.2-jar-with-    dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
}
```

Style.xml with a lot of things after, but for different theme name.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="StandardThemeX" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>
```

My activity(with theme StandardThemeX) that extends AppCompatActivity:

```
public class TestFont extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_font);

    TextView tvTest = this.findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
    Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.barcode);
    tvTest.setTypeface(typeface);

}
}
```

I want to make this work with XML definition of fontFamily, but it gives no errors to work with...

Comment: You can't have any underscores in a binary resource file, only in XML files. Try changing the filename of the TTF file to remove the underscore.